# C# Cannot implicity convert int[] to int

Tags: c#

```
public int[] kdPegawai;
if (Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxJumlahPegawai.Text) == 4)
{
    kdPegawai[1] = new int[] { Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text) };
}
```

I need to put value from combobox to kdPegawai array, but keep getting error like this:

> cannot implicitly convert int[] to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not assign a whole array to a single value in another array (unless it's a 2D array).

So this line should be changed to:

```
kdPegawai[1] = Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text);
```

And you have to initialize array before assigning any value to it.

If you just want to insert one value like you've shown in the code, then you can also do something like this:

```
kdPegawai = new int[] { Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text) };
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the OP wants to put the integer in the *second* position in the array.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote same as shown in the question. As any new bee also know that array index starts from 0. :)
Still thanks for mentioning it as few may get help through your comment. Up -vote to it.

Comment: thanks for the answer and explaination, i use this kdPegawai[0] = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text); and its work!

Answer (score 1):

Array value assignment is wrong

```
 public int[] kdPegawai = new int[1];
 if (Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxJumlahPegawai.Text) == 4)
        {
            kdPegawai[0] =  Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text) ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an array with a single item, try this instead:

```
public int[] kdPegawai;
if (Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxJumlahPegawai.Text) == 4)
{
    kdPegawai = new int[] { Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text) };
}
```

Recall that `kdPegawai[1] = ...` means that you're trying to assign something to the second item of the array, which (I assume) isn't what you're trying to do here. Also recall that the second item of the array is an integer, not an array of integers (hence the error).

A single-item array is pointless in most cases, though (unless you're doing a library call that requires you to pass an array or something like that). If it's only ever going to be a single item, consider just using an `int`.

Alternatively, you can initialize the array ahead of time and do something like:

```
kdPegawai[0] = Convert.ToInt16(comboBoxKdPegawai.Text);
```

**Important note:** `array[1]` is the *second* item in an array, *not* the first item. The first item in the array is `array[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough, it reminds you that you are trying to assign a integer array to an integer variable. Here we can see that `kdPegawai` is an integer array and hence any value at a valid index will be an integer(`kdPegawai[0]`) and you are trying to assign integer array to that causing the error. And Why there is too many conversions? why not do it like the following?

```
public int[] kdPegawai;

int intPegawai = 0;
if (int.TryParse(comboBoxJumlahPegawai.Text, out intPegawai) &&  intPegawai == 4)
{
    kdPegawai = new int[] { intPegawai };
}
```

Still I'm confused what is the need for array here, as you are dealing with a single value? why dont you proceed with `intPegawai`

Comment: no problem. also, I think he's checking the value of one combobox and assigning the value of another...